# Как отменить долгое выполнение запроса в БД из другого потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность, oracle, preparedstatement

Система построения отчетов берет данные с БД. Открывается курсор и данные льются в ecxel файл. работает все в цикле который крутиться в отдельном потоке. Одна итерация цыкла - один отчет - один запрос в бд. Но суть в другом. Запросы в бд бывают разными и есть значения по которым запрос может выполняться  стремясь к бесконечности, часами сутками. И вот такая ситуация - запущен цыкл из 10 шагов и на 3 шаге например попадается значение запрос с которым будет вполняться 24 часа. Пользователь не хочет ждать и хочет отменить выполнение. Варианты с timeout не подходят так как бывают запросы которые реально работают долго и это нормально. Грубо На интерфейсе отображается ход генерации и пользователь видит по какому значению сейчас выполняется отчет. И если он висит долго то пользователь сам проверяет это значение и принимает решение отменить генерацию или оставить. Так вот как реализовать отмену. Приложение висит на этой строке:

```
ps.executeQuery();//PreparedStatement
```

Я нарыл информацию что есть классный метод `cancel()` у класса `PreparedStatement`  который должен отменить выполнение. Но оказалось что он не такой классный и работает не так как хочеться. На английском стеке перерыл все и некоторые утверждают что этот метод не гарантирует отмену запроса в БД.
И у меня он тоже не работает. Я запускаю запрос на выполнение, потом отменяю его, метод отрабатывает без ошибок но сессия висит в базе. И только после убиения сессии руками в базе выбрасывается ексепшен в программе.

вот код. тут я создаю  `PreparedStatement`   и добавляю в кеш чтобы потом достать его в другом потоке и отменить:

```
StatementCache.getInstance().addToMap(resolutionId, ps);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                StatementCache.getInstance().removeFromMap(resolutionId);
```

А тут я пытаюсь отменить

```
PreparedStatement fromMap = StatementCache.getInstance().getFromMap(resolutionId);
        if (fromMap != null) {
            try {
                fromMap.cancel();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                return;
            }
            StatementCache.getInstance().removeFromMap(resolutionId);
        }
```

и все отрабатывает без ошибок. но сессию не обивает.

Вопрос: Как мне отменить выполнение долгого запроса в БД?

как вариант узнать в программе sessionId и выполнить kill сессии отдельным запросом. Но я не могу найти вариант узнать этот sessionId. и вариант кажеться слишком костыльным.

EDIT Если это поможет лучше понять как работает то вот еще код

```
public class StatementCache {
    private static volatile StatementCache instance;
    private ConcurrentMap<Long, PreparedStatement> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private StatementCache(){

    }

    public static StatementCache getInstance() {
        StatementCache local = instance;
        if (local == null) {
            synchronized (StatementCache.class) {
                local = instance;
                if (local == null) {
                    instance = local = new StatementCache();
                }
            }
        }
        return local;
    }


    public  void addToMap(Long id, PreparedStatement statement) {
        map.put(id, statement);
    }

    public  void removeFromMap(Long id) {
        map.remove(id);
    }

    public  PreparedStatement getFromMap(Long id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }
}
```

в одном потоке сюда кладется PreparedStatement  в другом достается и отменяется(оменяется уже запущеный).

Comment: @user5620472 может использовать готовый фремворк, например, `Hibernate`, который будет мочить ваши сессии сам ? тогда вам кэш не нужен будет

Comment: может надо оптимизировать запрос если он выполняется сутки?

Comment: ответ сразу всем. 1. оптимизировать запрос не получиться. так как он  консалидирует кучу данных по статистике абонентам сотовой связи, которую невозможно обрабатывать и складывать в какуюто таблицу в удобном виде так как это займет много ресурсов и по сути бесполезно. и тут суть в том что даже часовой запрос это норма если так нужно пользователю. он может захотеть отменить и запрос который минуту. 2. Hibernate когда он будет мочить мои сессии? когда выполнит запрос? мне веть отменить нужно запрос. 3. Проблема не в том как закрыть ресурс после выполнения запроса а как отменить запрос

Comment: система многопоточная и может генерироваться сарзу много отчетов. и кеш - это хранилище ссылок на PreparedStatement чтобы в главном потоке можно было узнать какой именно запрос оменять.